# Amazon EC2 how to close or recover a serial console session?

Tags: amazon-ec2, console

The relatively new serial console for EC2 servers is such a great relief. But I just ran into an issue where I closed the tab that had the console connection running. And when I wanted to get back to it, it said:

> The instance currently has 1 active serial console session. Only 1
> session is supported at a time.

is there a way to close that serial console session which no longer has a browser window associated with it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the only way to close a serial console open in a browser window is by closing the tab:

> To terminate the serial console session, close the serial console in-browser terminal window.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminate-serial-console-session.title.html

In my experience, however, sometimes the console seems to get stuck, and doesn't not allow a new session, even though the tab containing the previous one was closed properly. The message issued is the one you posted. In those cases, just waiting seems to fix the issue, and indeed this is the expected behaviour:

> It takes 30 seconds to tear down a session after you've disconnected from the serial console in order to allow a new session.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connect-to-serial-console.html